# Best practice for method with Map return

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

Suppose i have a method which has map as return type and uses generics.

I would like to know what is the best practice of filling that Map object.
Please see the snippet.

```
public Map<String,?> getEmployeeInfo(String query) {

Map<String,Object> dataMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    // do some op.

    String empId = "abc123";

    List<Long> projectIds = new ArrayList<Long>();

    List<String> performanceGoals = new ArrayList<String>();


    dataMap.put("empId",empId);
    dataMap.put("projectIds",projectIds);
    dataMap.put("performanceGoals",performanceGoals);

    return dataMap;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: He wants the best practice for a bad practice.

Comment: Ah, mediocre practices! Now that's my turf.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel I want to know if you have method which will return a map with generics what is best practice. I know you shouldn't be Map<String, String> if signature is like Map<String, extends Object>?

Comment: @jamesT: follow Christian's advice below. The moment you're going to create a collection of `Object`s that aren't really of type `Object` just to hold them together, you're most likely better off with a custom class.

Comment: But that way I will end with say 3-5 classes. I mean i will end up creating more classes etc.

Comment: Welcome to Object Oriented Design. We feast on classes. Maybe you can abstract some of them if they have similar purpose and functionality? If not, well, it's a whole lot better than creating a `Map` of fields.

Comment: Sounds really good to me. If you had said 300-500 Classes, but 3-5 is quite OK. Or ar all of this classes different Views for Employees?

Comment: Christian Kuetbach and Jeroen Vannevel, thanks for your comments and time. I already have a class for employee with fields. Since java allows generics and you can have a map to hold key,value. I want to know, what data type insertion will violate generics etc.

Answer (score 4):

The best practise is: Don't use this.

Make a Class Employee with members

```
public class Employee {
    String id; 
    List<Long> projectIds;
    List<String> performanceGoals;

    ...

}
```

And you method changes to:

```
public Employee getEmployeeInfo(String query) {
    ...
```

**update for clarification why returning Map is bad in general**

If your method returns:

`Map<String,?>` or `Map<String,? extends Object>` you say (in slang):

*Hey look here, I am returning something. Store it in a variable called "something", because I don't say anything about the value.*

If you write this method, you have to ensure, that you know every single line of code, where you work with your Map.

Lets say I would like to change `employeeId` from `String` to `Integer`. This will lead to really bad `RuntimeExceptions` and `ClassCastExceptions`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, appreciate it. I am looking for a scenario where say i have a class for it but I need a generic method with map with might return diffenert values to the caller etc.

Comment: Do you NEED a generic method or do you THINK that you need it? I mean your question sounds like "I want to write a OR mapper because JPA and Hibernate are not sufficient"

Comment: I do need it. query logic is separate and I do use proper collection for that. What i am trying to ask is if you have such map as returned type what to and what not to put in it etc in terms of best practice and performance concerns.

Comment: The best practice is: Don't use mixed Maps. About performance: I don't get the question. The creation of the values for the map will be far greater than the time spent on inserting them into the map.